# I want to add a functionality that the user can change the theme of the app by selecting one of the popUp menu Items in appBar

Tags: flutter, user-interface, material-ui, setstate, flutter-change-notifier

I'm fairly new to the application development using Flutter.
I have been trying to solve a problem where I want to implement a functionality in my flutter app, that the user can change the theme of the whole app with the help of a colours in a popup menu located in the appBar.
[The proposed popUp menu with all the colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaW4i.png)

```
Map<BackgroundColors, Color> backGround = {
  BackgroundColors.yellow: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 227, 146, 1),
  BackgroundColors.purple: const Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 192, 233),
  BackgroundColors.green: const Color.fromARGB(255, 172, 227, 174),
  BackgroundColors.blue: const Color.fromARGB(255, 158, 197, 229),
  BackgroundColors.pink: const Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 170, 188),
};

final ValueNotifier<BackgroundColors> backgroundColors =
    ValueNotifier(BackgroundColors.yellow);
ValueNotifier<Color> seedColor =`your text`
    ValueNotifier(backGround[backgroundColors.value]!);
```

This is the part of the main.dart file and `enum BackgroundColors` is in another global.dart file

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void setSeedColor() {
    seedColor.value = backGround[backgroundColors.value]!;
  }

  final kColorScheme = ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    seedColor: seedColor.value,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<Color>(
      valueListenable: seedColor,
      builder: (context, Color color, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
          theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: kColorScheme,
            appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme().copyWith(
              backgroundColor: kColorScheme.inversePrimary,
              foregroundColor: kColorScheme.inverseSurface,
            ),
            bottomSheetTheme: const BottomSheetThemeData().copyWith(
              backgroundColor: kColorScheme.onTertiary,
              showDragHandle: true,
            ),
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Expenses(
            backgroundColors: backgroundColors.value,
            onColorchange: setSeedColor,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the `_MyAppState` class in the main.dart file which I configured for the `ThemeMode.light`
I added ValueListener class for both the `BackgroundColors` and `seedColor` as the popUp menu changes the value of `BackgroundColors` and then called a `setState()` function `setSeedColor` to update the seedColor for the `colorScheme`